# delete part of object js

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have array of string smth like this:

myarray = ["first word","second word","smth more",]

I need to delete each second word from array.

result:

```
myarray = ["first","second","smth",]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried so far to solve this? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var yourArray = ["first word","second word","smth more"];

var yourNewArray = yourArray.map( item => { 
   return item.split(' ')[0];
});


console.log(yourNewArray);
```

or about the same with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var yourArray = ["first word","second word","smth more"];
var yourNewArray = [];

yourArray.forEach( item => {
    yourNewArray.push(item.split(' ')[0])
});

console.log(yourNewArray);
```

Comment: Why do you use Spread syntax on `yourArray` ? it is obvuisly an Array isn't it ?

Comment: @CedricCholley good question! I have no idea, will remove it! thanks